# Angular httpclient.post send a JSON Obj to ASP.Net Core Action, at back-end data received is null

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, http-post

I have a project that is ASP.Net Core and Angular. I am trying to do a very simple operation, from Angular posting a JSON data format to the back-end ASP.Net Core. The flow seems to work, it calls the correct Action at the back-end, however the data pass is null. Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

At the Front-End, I have a simple Object that holds the data and at constructor I cast it to JSON. I verified that at the  http.post call the data part contain the JSON information. So at the call below the jsonMessageFormat has the correct information.

```
   this._http.post(this._baseUrl + 'fabAutomation/PostTest', 
    this.jsonMessageFormat, this.config).subscribe(result => {
    this._returnedResult = result;
     }, error => console.error(error));
```

At the back end I tried to set the PostTest Action to accept both:
1. string 
2. [FromBody] format to convert from JSON to the model

Neither, option worked. And at the Back-End Action the received data is null.

At the front-end:

```
   fabAutomationJsonMessage: any = [{ "maskID": "AAAA", "recipeName": 
   "XXXX", "JobTypeCduOrReg": "reg", "cduRevNumber": "0", "regRevNumber": 
  "0", "recipeState": null, "reticleAvailability": "eee", "dateTime": 
  "ddd" }];

   jsonMessageFormat: JSON;


 config: any = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.set('Accept', 'application/json')




     constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string)
        {
       this.jsonMessageFormat = <JSON>this.fabAutomationJsonMessage;
        this._http = http;
       this._baseUrl = baseUrl;
        }


forSubmitOnClick() {

this._http.post(this._baseUrl + 'fabAutomation/PostTest', 
this.jsonMessageFormat, this.config).subscribe(result => {
  this._returnedResult = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

//At the BackEnd:

//At the Controller, define the following Action, the fabAutomationMessageVMOBJ  is always null

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IActionResult PostTest([FromBody] fabAutomationMessageVM 
        fabAutomationJsonMessageVMOBJ)
          {


        //removed implementation for simplicity


            //for response simply return the same information
            return Json(fabAutomationJsonMessageVMOBJ);


          }
```

Since the whole flow is working, and the http.post contain the Data in a JSON format (not null), I expect that this data will pass to the back-end as none-null.

Comment: `fabAutomationJsonMessage` can be passed as is. You don't really need to type cast it to `<JSON>`

Comment: try sending fabAutomationJsonMessage instead of jsonMessageFormat , and even headers can be removed.

Comment: Most likely you can just drop the `[FromBody]` from your Action

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented all three suggestions here, and remove the header obj from the http.post. The fabAutomationJsonMessageVMOBJ is now not null(after removing the [] from the front-end assignment resolve that issue); however, the current behavior is the fields of this object are all null. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your asp.net core web api receives an entity of model `fabAutomationMessageVM`

```
public IActionResult PostTest([FromBody] fabAutomationMessageVM fabAutomationJsonMessageVMOBJ)
```

but you post an array for your `fabAutomationJsonMessage` in angular and it will have `400` error when I test that, try to remove the `[]`

```
fabAutomationJsonMessage: any = { 
       "maskID": "AAAA", 
       "recipeName": 
       "XXXX", "JobTypeCduOrReg": "reg", 
       "cduRevNumber": "0", 
       "regRevNumber": "0", 
       "recipeState": null, 
       "reticleAvailability": "eee", 
       "dateTime": "ddd" 
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, much appreciated!

Comment: I have removed the [] from the JSON Object, as suggested by Xing Zou, and that resolved the back-end from receiving a null, object. However, the fields of this object are all at null values. I also cast the fabAutomationJsonMessage object directly (not casting to JSON), and also removed the config (the header object that goes with the http.post)

Comment: @AsafD You could open your browser, press F12, click network tab to see what data you have posted.If you receives data using `[FromBody]`, the` config` is necessary and you should not remove the `config`.Besides, your model `fabAutomationMessageVM` is required to have above properities.

Comment: @AsafD Do you have any errors in console tab with F12?

Comment: Hi Xing Zou, thanks for your help, here is the output from the Network tab(it does include the values): {maskID: "AAAA", recipeName: "XXXX", JobTypeCduOrReg: "reg", cduRevNumber: "0", regRevNumber: "0",…}
JobTypeCduOrReg: "reg"
cduRevNumber: "0"
dateTime: "ddd"
maskID: "AAAA"
recipeName: "XXXX"
recipeState: "null"
regRevNumber: "0"
reticleAvailability: "eee"

Comment: Also, the header seems to include the content-type as JSON. But one thing that I notice here is that it is using https and not http, could that be the problem? see below:                                                                     
                          application/json, text/plain, */*
                         Content-Type: application/json
                         Origin: https://localhost:44385
                          Referer: https://localhost:44385/
                          Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Comment: I noticed, when I copy/paste the header(at the above comment) it omits the, https:, in front of the //local:PortID. Also, no error at the F12 (Network, or Console)- Status Code is green and is 200.

Comment: Ok, I have just published the site, so now it does not use the https, but still the issue. So it seems that it is not an https vs. http issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank you all for helping, a specially to Xing Zou that stayed with me. I found that the problem was with the viewModel. Although I declared the class public, I found that I have to declare each of the members public as well.